# How to wait for API in Selenium if JQuery is not implemented in the application?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application, we are not using `JQuery`, and instead we use standard js using `xmlhttprequest` web APIs.

Here is the selenium snippet we generally use if the application waits for ajax with JQuery implementation:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)
wait.until { @driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active").to_i == 0 }
```

How can we handle `wait_for_ajax`/`wait for API response call` if the application doesn't support JQuery?

Comment: When are you exactly waiting for the `jQuery` to complete? On `pageLoad` or after `clicking any button`?

Comment: usually on pagination, auto-complete, etc., ; we use php for backend scripting, usually an api call will be made whenever I do pagination, etc., In our current application, we are no longer using JQuery, so wherever I wait for JQuery to complete, its of no use

Comment: Can you narrow down your question and be more specific exactly for which action you want to handle the `jQuery`?

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't want to handle JQuery since we are not using JQuery in the application itself and they don't work either; the question is, how to handle wait for ajax or API response if there is no JQuery implementation in the application?

Comment: But you need to understand how the particular `Ajax Call` comes into existence? Is it during initial `pageLoad` or on some button `click()`? We handle them differently.

Comment: @DebanjanB it happens on some actions after the pageload

Answer (score 0):

The way I generally handle this is to wait for the page to load by waiting for a specific element (or group of elements) to be visible on the page. Once that condition is met, the page is loaded.

If after the page is loaded you perform some action on the page that triggers part of the page to reload, you would then find an element in the dynamic portion of the page to wait for which would indicate that the dynamic load is done.

I use the page object model so I take care of page load in my page object constructor and any dynamic issues I handle in the method that triggers the action, e.g. clickButton() would not only click the button but have a wait that waits for the dynamic load to finish.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your Question `if the application doesn't support JQuery` the simple alternatively will be to use **`WebDriverWait`** to get back the availability of the next intended element as follows :

- **`WebDriverWait`**

  ```
  WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Id("next_intended_element_id")));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In my java code I do like this :

```
//Wait for JQuery Load
public static void waitForJQueryLoad() {
    //Wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = driver -> ((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) jsWaitDriver)
            .executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);

    //Get JQuery is Ready
    boolean jqueryReady = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return jQuery.active==0");

    //Wait JQuery until it is Ready!
    if(!jqueryReady) {
        System.out.println("JQuery is NOT Ready!");
        //Wait for jQuery to load
        jsWait.until(jQueryLoad);
    } else {
        System.out.println("JQuery is Ready!");
    }
}
```